# 50s synonym for "snogging"

Tags: synonyms, british-english

What would the British term in 1954 have been for "snogging"? "Making out" is American. "All over each other" doesn't seem quite specific enough.

Comment: The 50s American slang was *necking* rather than *making out*, which is a modern idiom.

Comment: @DanBron: Perhaps ironically, _necking_ is coming back into "fashion" amongst certain classes in the modern UK's East Midlands area at least.

Comment: The original (Indian?) sense was "cuddling, fondling". Over time I think it's become more specifically "kissing" in BrE, but back in the 50s, **spooning** would probably have been a fairly common (and for the time, *accurate*) synonym.

Comment: Before I realised you were looking for a British-specific phrase, the first word that came to mind was *smooching*. Interestingly, an Ngram (https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=smooching&year_start=1920&year_end=2015&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csmooching%3B%2Cc0) shows very little usage in the 50s, but increasingly more popular from the 80s to now. Interestingly, it's much the same for American English - a minor peak in the 50s, but *far* more popular now, even though I would have guessed it was an outdated term.

Answer (score 12):

***[Petting](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/petting)***

> The act or practice of amorously embracing, kissing, and caressing one's partner.
>   <sub>thefreedictionary.com</sub>

The Oxford English Dictionary lists this word as having originated in 16th century England, so it would certainly have been around in the fifties.

A Google Ngrams search reveals that *snogging* was very rarely used back then. Interestingly however, the word ***osculating*** (which I had never come across until researching this answer) seems to have been used fairly often, although it's not certain as to whether it was being used to mean *kiss* in the human sense.

[image: petting,snogging,osculating]

---

As an aside, including 'kissing' in the above graph shows just how much more popular it was.

[image: petting,snogging,kissing,osculating]

Comment: Perhaps a Google Ngram is required here https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=was+petting%2Cwere+petting%2C+petting&year_start=1920&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwas%20petting%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwere%20petting%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpetting%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Don't forget: *heavy petting* :)) Be wary of the verb *to pet* which was used to a express affection, and innocent caresses.

Comment: At least in the US, necking and petting were very different things. Necking was just kissing, while petting was anything more intimate short of intercourse.

Answer (score 10):

It's quite likely that *snogging* would actually have been used in Fifties Britain.

OED records written usage, which would lag behind spoken use.

> 1945   C. H. Ward-Jackson *Piece of Cake* (ed. 2) 56   Snogging, courting, running around with the opposite sex. Comes from India. Thus, ‘On my leave I'm going up to the hills for a bit of snogging.’ Also used as a verb.
>   1951   *Sunday Pictorial* 28 Oct. 10/6   Few hounds can get in more than half an hour of ‘snogging’—their elegant term for not-too-serious courtship.
>   1960   N. Epton *Love & English* vi. 341   It is all right..to cuddle. (The current term among teen-agers is ‘snogging’.)

Answer (score 4):

I looked up my favorite *canoodling* in Ngrams and even though its initial peak was around the 30', when compared to *snogging*:

[image]

in the year 1954, canoodling has **0.0000002822%** whereas snogging has "only" **0.0000000415%** - that is 6.8 times less.

Answer (score 1):

*Necking* is another possibility. It [scores higher on n-grams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=necking%2Csnogging%2Cheavy%20petting&year_start=1920&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnecking%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csnogging%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cheavy%20petting%3B%2Cc0) than "heavy petting" or "snogging", peaking just before the 1950's.